# Shouldn't there be "ends" instead of "end" in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I read a definition of the word "pylon" in Merriam Webster dictionary which was

> A tower for supporting either end of usually a number of wires over a long span

I suspect that "ends" could also be used there counting wires individually. But the author might have used "end" because he thought of wires as a bundle. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

There must be *singular* in combination with *either* (either end = **each end** of those 2 a wire has; that remains true for a number of wires).

Comment: To add more context to this, a plural would be used with *both*.